# Get the actual DB size from the backup file without restore

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

Is there any way to get the size of the DB without restoring a backup file?

For example: I have a backup file of 10 GB, I want to know the size of the DB after the backup file will be restored. Most of the times the DB size is much larger than its backup file because of free spaces in DB. So is there anyway to know the DB size without restoring only from backup file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [RESTORE FILELISTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173778.aspx) to get the size like below

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'D:\backup_filename.bak'
```

It doesn't actually restore rather returns a result set containing a list of the database and log files contained in the backup set in SQL Server. Result includes `Size` column which gives the size in bytes.

> Size numeric(20,0) Current size in bytes.